# Overriding default constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

Pretty easy question, but anyway: is there any reason to override default constructor  like this:

```
public SomeObject(){
}
```

It is public. It is does not have any logic. So, is there necessary? I didn't see the whole picture?

Appreciate all your help.

Comment: Not really, but it allows for a few seconds saved in the future if you need to add some code when you instantiate the object.  `private SomeObject() { }` however does make a bit more sense :) -- also in C++ it's common courtesy to include the `::SomeObject() { }` and `::~SomeObject() { }` even if they're not used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One reason to define *an empty* no-arg constructor is if there is *also* a non-default constructor and the no-arg constructor is still desired to be accessible (public or protected).

This is because any [other] constructor definition [will prevent the automatic addition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) of the default no-arg constructor:

> The compiler automatically provides a [public] no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.

(See the next bit in that link as well, where it talks about the default super constructor that will be called.)

Even if the no-arg constructor is never used manually, it can be important for other things, e.g. [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the class. *A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is serializable.* The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored from the stream.

Comment: This is the right answer. On another note, if you're developing in Android and you don't provide a no-arg constructor in a Fragment that has non-default constructor(s) you'll get a crash when waking up your app from sleep because the system uses the no-arg constructor to instantiate your Fragment.

Comment: Thank you. Simple and comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 4):

Only reason may be, sometimes you may have constructor with parameters and you want to allow object creation without passing parameters (by invoking default constructor).

When you have constructor defined, no arg constructor won't be available, so you have to explicitly add it to your class.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have any initialization logic there is no need for overriding the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The exact reason is, if you don't, you will have problem while extending classes

```
class A{
    int a;
    public A(int a){
        this.a=a;
    }
    // public A()
    //{
        // here super(); will be called again, calling Object class's constructor thus initializing any uninitialized variables
    //}
}

class B extends A{
    int b;
    public B(int b){
        // here automatically, "super();" will be executed. if it is not present, error!
        this.b=b;
    }
}
```

go through [this](http://ideone.com/5vw1u) and [this](http://ideone.com/7wREv) to understand what I was trying to say.

EDIT: some of the answers are actually wrong because as you can see, defining the parent no-arg constructor is mandatory while extending classes unless you will explicitly call overloaded super constructor with args.

Comment: It's _not_ needed **IF** you are implicitly calling overloaded constructor. So, you can't say it is _not_, like it is _not_ at all! O_O