# Why are the fields of my super class getting initialized here ?

Tags: java

I'd like someone to verify whether my understanding is correct. 
I've some code like this:

```
public class A {
int a;
int b;
public A(int a)
{
    this.a=a;
}
```

Now A() is a constructor I've defined which means it is not the default constructor. 
So, if I have a subclass that extends this class.

```
public class B extends A{
public B()
{ 
   super(15);
}

}
```

If I print values of both a and b in the subclass, I see a gets a value of 15 and b gets a value of 0. When I have explicitly defined a constructor in A which means it isn't the default constructor, then how is the uninitialized field of b in the class A getting the value of 0 ?

Answer (score 6):

`int` is a primitive type and can't be `null`. The default value is `0`.

Comment: But who assigns this initial value to b ?

Comment: Java does automatically http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: okay in the situation i have described, a default constructor is not getting called anywhere correct to initialize uninitialized field of b ?

Comment: Yes. You are calling a non default constructor. The default one won't be called too.

Comment: Yes. The choice that class fields are initialized (with 0, null, false) and local variables not, was made intentionally. Not initializing class fields would mean less quality code, and often superfluous extra initialisation, whereas not initializing local variables can be detected by the compiler.

Comment: My point is if the default constructor is providing any initialization for uninitialized class fields and if not, if the class fields are automatically getting initialized then why does one need to have a default constructor ?

Comment: If you don't need any parameters you can use a default constructor. And you can call the default constructor from another constructor. Example: `public SomeClass(int i) { this(); }`

Comment: @Phoenix check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849942/overriding-default-constructor-in-java/11850274#11850274) for why you should use no arg constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The [relevant part of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) says that class fields are *automatically* initialized with their default value if one is not specified.

Comment: Does it happen without calling the default constructor ?

Comment: @Phoenix: yes. Try creating a default constructor with a `System.out.println` statement.

Comment: When you instantiate an object (by calling a constructor), all fields are initialized.  primitives are initialized to reasonable values (0 for numbers, false for boolean, etc...) since they cannot be null.  All non-primitives are initialized to null.  Then your constructor is called along with any "initialization blocks" (google this if you don't understand what this means)

Answer (score 0):

In this case the uninitialized field b gets the default value 0 for int in java.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

Answer (score 0):

Default values for primitive types are set by `Object` class's constructor. When you initialize an object of `B`, it's being called here..

in `public A(int a)`, `super();` is first executed automatically, and thus the `b` acquires `0` due to `Object`'s `public Object()` constructor being called here.

Source: Complete Reference JAVA \m/